# can't import own class

Tags: java, import

I have `PhotosScanner.java` and `PhotosScanner.class` in same folder with `Main.java`.
And now I want to use `PhotosScanner` in the class `Main` with this code:

```
import PhotosScanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PhotosScanner ps = new PhotosScanner();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile `Main.java`, then I get this error:

```
d:\space\NewPhotos>javac Main.java
Main.java:1: error: '.' expected
import PhotosScanner;
                    ^
Main.java:1: error: ';' expected
import PhotosScanner;
                    ^
2 errors
```

In Java 7 it compiles without errors (I'm using Java 8 now).
How can I import my `PhotosScanner` class?

Comment: Please show us your package hierarchy

Comment: Wait. PhotosScanner is a package?

Comment: no , it's class
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8iesi13990y5tep/file.png?dl=0)

Comment: Please use packages. The default package is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports in Java are used for importing Classes from outside the current package.

**You don't need to import the class from the same package.**

Answer (score 1):

> > I have PhotosScanner.java and PhotosScanner.class in same folder with Main.java

You dont need to import as they reside in same folder (i.e. same package).

You need to import when you try to use class from other package.

Comment: Again downvoted. Is somebody personal? I dont see a reason for downvoted. Every answer ends up with down vote. @downvoter can you please please paste a comment...

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. It'll be auto-reversed at the end of the day if it is always the same person